# Displaying stack items in multiple text boxes

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to java and writing a program that is basically a calculator and when a value is pushed, it displays that value (shows top of stack). For that last part of the assignment, it says to "instead of displaying only the top item in the stack, use 10 text boxes stacked one on top of the other to display all items in the stack, with the top item on the top". I have no idea what would be the most effective way to do this without writing a million lines of code so if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be great help

Comment: Your question is too broad, what framework are you using? Swing, JavaFX, SWT, GWT, HTML?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array of text boxes, and use a loop to show up to ten items from the stack in it.

Your code controls the stack, so it knows when its state changes due to a push or a pop operation. When this happens, call a method to refresh the representation of your stack. The method goes through the top ten items, and copies their content to the text boxes. When the stack has fewer than ten items, the method should blank out the remaining text boxes.

Making an array of check boxes and writing an update routine should take up roughly a few dozen lines of code, so it shouldn't be too difficult to implement.